# What are my hosting options for an app that needs tilestashe alongside a django app?

Tags: python, django, hosting, gis

I'm building a GIS-ish webapp that uses [tilestache](http://tilestache.org/) to serve MBTiles and a django app to serve user specified geoJson. I'm having trouble understanding exactly what kind of setup I'd need to host this. I'm new to server admin and setup, so something heroku-ish would be nice, but I'd be willing to learn if the solution involved something more low level.

Comment: I don't have experience with heroku (and what it allows) but it sounds like you will need to run your own VPS instance. I user [Linode](http://linode.com) and they are fantastic. Here's some things to read up on: virutalenv & virtualenvwrapper (for encapsulating python envirnoments), nginx (web proxy), uwsgi (application server - also check out gunicorn as an alternative), supervisor (process manager)

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony Thanks for your suggestions! I ended up hosted on a single AWS instance with gunicorn workers for tilestache and django `proxy_pass`'ed through nginx. So far, so good. Certainly supervisor and fabric (or the like) will be coming soon. The sites on my profile if you're interested. Thanks again!